# What are the best practices for tagging questions?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question which refers to a specific stack or package how should I tag it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-tagging-questions?/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Questions relating to specific stacks should be tagged with the stacks name.  And questions relating to a specific package should be tagged with both the stack and package name if possible.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8